# DevExpress cascading comboboxes in datagridview

Tags: c#, devexpress, cascadingdropdown

I have a datagridview bound to a datasource, and in each row in the grid there is a category, product, and quantity. I want to filter the products in each row according to the selected category.
I'm using C# and DevExpress. How can I do this?

[image: GridExample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the [How to filter a second LookUp column based on a first LookUp column's value](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/kb/p/A237.aspx) article which explains how to implement this feature.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how You want to filter you can set

```
gridView1.OptionsCustomization.AllowFilter = true;
```

This will display an additional filter row in your grid that will allow you to filter all columns by any text you want;

Or you can make sure that `gridView1.OptionsCustomization.AllowFilter` is set to true. Then there should be little icon on your column header (visible in right top corner when you move cursor over the column header) that will display filter after you click it.